# How many long to double cast I need

Tags: java, casting

I want to calculate Naive Bayes probability. The calculation is :

```
Math.Log((n1+1)/(n2+n3))/Math.Log(2)
```

The result should be in double, where n1..n3 are long. How do I cast it?

My current cast like this

```
Math.Log((double)(n1+1)/(n2+n3))/Math.Log(2)
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Math.log`

Comment: Does your current cast not work for some reason...?

Comment: it's work but just make sure it's true for all condition, need some advice

Comment: One is enough, or less `Math.log((n1+1.0)/(n2+n3))/Math.log(2)` the use of a `1.0` turns it into a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current cast will work correctly. If either of the operands of the division is a double, the other will be cast to a double too.

See the [Java Language Specification on Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Widening primitive conversion is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.